# IntelliJ optimize imports adds space

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I do optimize imports in IntelliJ (`CTRL` + `ALT` + `O`) I get two (according to me) weird consequences.

1. The imports go from alphabetical order --> not alphabetical order
2. A space is added between imports and `java.util` imports.

Example before optimize:

```
import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
```

Example after optimize:

```
import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
```

Why is it that `java.util` packages seem to get some special treatment and end up here in the bottom with an additional space before them?

Comment: I’m not sure about IntelliJ, but for Eclipse there is a setting, I would expect one for IntelliJ too. There’s probably a default setting that says that the java package should be separate and separated from the others by a blank line. If so, you can change that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The import organizing is defined at File/Settings menu, under Editor/Code Style/Java, in the Import Layout section (assuming IDEA 14). In your case I suppose it contains com.* , followed by org.* , followed by blank line, followed by java.* etc. You can customize it here according to your needs.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it! I had a look there but did not notice the blank line entities in the list. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but if someone came across this answer looking to add spaces to the import brackets in JS projects, it's at File/Settings menu -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Spaces -> ES6 import/export braces. [See also](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000204010-Format-Space-within-braces-for-ES6-import-export)